# Apache xampp does not start

Tags: apache, xampp

I have the old problem with xampp and Apache and Apache not starting.
This is a windows 10 machine running xampp-win32-5.6.31-0-VC11. I also tried 7.1.9-0-VC14 with the same problems. 
The problem is:

```
12:47:45 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:47:45 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:47:45 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:47:45 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:47:45 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:47:45 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:47:45 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

Log files on xampp are empty. 
I changed the ports 80 to 8080 and 443 to 4433 in the config files (found on the internet). I checked the netstat tool (both on xampp and on powershell). netstat on xampp did not show anything on port 80, 8080, 443, or 4433. 
netstat -aon on powershell gives a long output with the only "80"thing here:

```
TCP    192.168.88.125:49203   185.22.69.180:80       TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.88.125:65508   185.22.69.180:80       TIME_WAIT       0
```

and the only "443" thing here:

```
TCP    10.145.128.214:64112   10.144.187.242:443     TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.88.125:49320   40.77.229.18:443       ESTABLISHED     6728
TCP    192.168.88.125:49694   40.77.229.47:443       ESTABLISHED     6728
TCP    192.168.88.125:63719   2.20.161.124:443       CLOSE_WAIT      10168
TCP    192.168.88.125:64019   151.101.65.69:443      ESTABLISHED     2080
```

So, no occurrence of 8080 or 4433 on either netstat on xampps or netstat on powershell.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?
By the way: I do not have admin privileges. But I know people with the same kind of privileges that are able to run xampp.
I am able to run installers with something very close to admin rights - I can find out exactly what these rights are.
I did run xampp installer using these privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment so asking in answer section.

Do you have skype or any proxy running on system?

Comment: Skype is running but I cannot configure it. Neither port 80 nor port 8080 nor port 443 nor port 4433 are blocked according to netstat views, as shown above. Ports have been configured to be 8080 and 4433 in the configfile. Port 8080 seems to be ok, a zeppelin installation runs on it (Note: I do not run zeppelin server and xampp apache at the same time).